# Sum of elements in nested list using for loop

Tags: python, loops, nested, sum, iteration

I am an absolute beginner in python so please guide me where wrong. I have a nested list of scores for which I need to calculate the sum of all positive integers and the [-1] index.
I have converted the nested loop into flatlist and now tried the sum but I seem to be getting the total as 0. Answer should be 3150.

Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

```
#Create a 2D matrix with scores

#matrix (Column, Row) is a list of lists

matrix = [[0,-1000,0,0,0], [0,0,150,0,-1000], [0,-1000,1000,-1000,0], [-1000,1000,-1000,-150,0], [1000,150,0,0,-150]]

#convert nested list into flatlist

matrix_flatList = [ item for elem in matrix for item in elem]
print(matrix_flatList) 

def dream_score(matrix_flatlist):
    """
    A function that returns the max possible score 
    """
total = 0

#Iterate each positive element in list and add them in variable total

n = len(matrix_flatList)
for i in range(0,n): 
    if i > 0 and i == -150:
        total == total + matrix_flatList[i]
   
#printing dream score

print("Dream score is: ", total)
            
    
#make sure to get the last variable in total even if its negative

#return final score
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation so we can see which lines are in the function.

Comment: ``if i > 0 and i == -150:`` will never be possible...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: Why are you converting it into a flat list?

Comment: `i == -150` can never be true -- `i` is numbers starting from `0`.

Comment: I think you mean `if matrix_flatlist[i] > 0 or matrix_flatlist[i] == -150:`

Comment: `total == total + matrix_flatList[i]` is a typo that means you compare values, and never reassign `total` even if the `if` test passes. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality comparison.

Comment: Thankyou all for your input. I am learning how to sum the positive integers in this matrix / nested loop. My approach was to convert it into a flatlist... I understand i == -150 is hardcoding and is not the correct approach.                                                  
 The assignment requires to include the last element  irrespective of it being positive or negative. Thats where I think this approach may not be the correct one.

Comment: How do I approach it as (column, row) ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens in

```
if i > 0 and i == -150:
```

`i` can not be a positive value and -150 at the same time.

Maybe you want to use `or` instead.

Also if you want to find the element with index -1, it would be better to use the list indexing instead of using -150 explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your for loop to get the exact output.

```
#n = len(matrix_flatList)
for i in matrix_flatList: 
    if i > 0:
        total = total + i

#to add the last element of matrix_flatList in total 
total = total + matrix_flatList[-1]
#printing dream score

print("Dream score is:", total)
```

Output: `Dream score is: 3150`

Comment: The assignment requires to include the last element in the sum irrespective of it being positive or negative. Here index -1 is -150. Thats why

Comment: @diyer13619, I have just updated my answer. Hope it helps you.